# Python module import - why is it not working?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to install LLDB-3.5 on my system, and I'm having incredibly difficult time getting the python2.7 binding modules to load.

The module has the usual structure

```
/ LLDB
      + __init__.py
      + some_file.py
      + _lldb.so
      / subdirectory
```

I've verified that path to the module is in PYTHONPATH.  I've checked the results of sys.path, its there, and I can directly import some_file.py

```
import some_file # This line compiles happily.
```

Weirdly, I can also import **init**.py

```
import __init__ # This line complains its missing module lldb.some_file
```

I did have lldb-3.4 installed, but if I add a print statement in that file, it displays, so I'm definitely looking at this file.

However, when I try to import lldb, I get back

```
import lldb  # ImportError: No module named lldb
```

I don't understand that.

It's a swig'ed Python wrapper to LLDB, but I've verified that the .so loads.  calling "ldd _lldb.so" on the command line shows a good list of resolved dependencies.  If I run the commands in **init**.py in the python shell, (ie, the calls to imp.find_module & imp.load_module) then the so file is loaded happily.

I'm sure this is a very basic issue, but I'm don't use Python much. I've do have virtualenv installed with Python 2.6, but I have of course verified I'm in the right version of Python.

Comment: Your example shows the directory named `LLDB`.  Is it named `LLDB` (uppercase) or `lldb` (lowercase)?  Also, how did you install the library?

Comment: lldb - all lower case (sorry, will edit).  This is on ubuntu 14.10, and I apt-get installed lldb

Comment: I think the path isn't the problem, because as I said I can import individual py files from that folder

Comment: Is the `lldb` directory itself on the path?  For a package, you should have its containing directory (the parent directory of `lldb`) on `sys.path`.

Comment: FUUAUUAFFUUAUFUUFU... yup, thats it.  Add it as an answer and I'll accept it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the lldb directory itself on the path? For a package, you should have its containing directory (the parent directory of `lldb`) on sys.path.

(Normally I would expect the package installation to do this for you.  However, the note at the very end of [this page](http://lldb.llvm.org/build.html#BuildingLldbOnLinux) suggests that they're targeting the use case where you use the Python `lldb` module from within the `lldb` command-line program.  So you have to set up the path manually.)